# The MIN() Function Ms Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, aggregate-functions

this is a sample sql query that i created ms access query. i am trying to get only one row the min(DATE). how ever when i run my query i get multiple lines. any hits? thanks

```
SELECT tblWarehouseItem.whiItemName,
       tblWarehouseItem.whiQty, 
       tblWarehouseItem.whiPrice, 
       Min(tblWarehouseItem.whiDateIn) AS MinOfwhiDateIn, 
       tblWarehouseItem.whiExpiryDate, 
       tblWarehouseItem.whiwrhID
FROM tblWarehouseItem
GROUP BY tblWarehouseItem.whiDateIn,
         tblWarehouseItem.whiItemName,
         tblWarehouseItem.whiQty,
         tblWarehouseItem.whiPrice,
         tblWarehouseItem.whiExpiryDate,
         tblWarehouseItem.whiwrhID;
```

If i have my sql code like that is working as it should:

```
SELECT MIN(tblWarehouseItem.whiDateIn) FROM tblWarehouseItem;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT WI.*
FROM tblWarehouseItem AS WI INNER JOIN (SELECT whiimtID, MIN(tblWarehouseItem.whiDateIn) AS whiDateIn
          FROM tblWarehouseItem
        GROUP BY whiimtID)  AS MinWI ON (WI.whiDateIn = MinWI.whiDateIn) AND (WI.whiimtID = MinWI.whiimtID);
```

Answer (score 3):

In the first query, you group by a number of columns. That means the minimum value will be calculated for each group, which in turn means you may have multiple rows. On the other hand, the second query will only get the minimum value for the specified column from all rows, so that there is only one row in the result set.

A simple example is shown below to illustrate the above.

```
Table:
Key Value
1  1
1  2
2  3
2  4
```

On `Group By Key`:

```
GroupKey MinValue
1        = min(1,2) = 1 -> Row 1
2        = min(3,4) = 3 -> Row 2
```

On `Min (Value)`

```
MinValue
=min(1,2,3,4) = 1 -> Row 1
```

For a table like above, if you want to select all rows and also show the minimum value from whole table rather than per group, you can do something like this:

```
select key, (select min(value) from table)
from table
```

Comment: how can i rewrite my sql to output one row the min of that table but keeping all the fields?